# How to configure OSM tile Server?

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

i tried to install OSM tile server in the manual https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/
, and i installed it, but unfortunately i  don't understand, why it's still not work. Can anybody tell me, after the manual, tiles should generate on the fly or we have to generate before use ?
P.S I have tried many manuals but still don't understand how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

They're generated on the fly.

You can check the OpenTileServer bash script for checking your process
http://opentileserver.org/

In case of image tiles you should have a renderd daemon active.

Comment: I fond decision of my problem. In manual we use custom mapnik style, which didn't work for me. I downloaded mapnik additional scripts from
http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik